# How can i have a web page remember the page it was linked to from?

Tags: html

Here's the situation. i have a page with a link for "bands". when a user clicks that link they get a dropdown with different regions to choose from. when they choose a region they are directed to a regional page (ex. chicago / midwest). on that page are many links to different band pages. when the user clicks a specific band they are taken to that band's page (which may also be accessible from other regional pages). **here's where i need help**. right now there is a "bands" breadcrumb link at the top but since the specific band page does not know the region that was chosen, i have to present the regional dropdown list again. it would be nice if the information was passed to the specific band page so the user could just click "bands" and automatically be directed back to the correct regional page (in this case chicago / midwest).

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is generally done with server-side code, not HTML.  You can track recent searches/selections in a user's session and pre-populate fields on a page with that information.

Comment: thanks so much for the replies. unfortunately my coding is limited to html and css (yeah, i'm a designer, but i'm trying). any suggestions on where to start?